# OpenCV error: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in adaptiveThreshold when tring to use it in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, opencv, keras

When I'm trying to use `edge_detection` function inside `ImageDataGenerator` I'm getting this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-oxjbfc17/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1676: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'
```

but it works just fine if I used it outside the `ImageDataGenerator`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2

def edge_detection(frame):
    minValue = 70
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(5,5),2)
    th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
    ret, res = cv2.threshold(th3, minValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return res

img = cv2.imread('asl_alphabet_train/K/K1004.jpg', 0)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img)
img = edge_detection(img)        #here the function is working
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(img);

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 1), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(29, activation='softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=edge_detection,
        validation_split=0.1,
        dtype='uint8'
        )
train_data_gen = data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        "asl_alphabet_train",
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training',
        color_mode='grayscale'
        )
test_data_gen = data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        "asl_alphabet_train",
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=64,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation',
        color_mode='grayscale'
        )

classifier.fit(           #here I'm getting the error when trying to load the image and apply the function via ImageDataGenerator
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=1224,
          epochs=6,
          validation_data=test_data_gen,
          validation_steps=136)
```

[image: These photos are examples to see that the function is working outside the ImageDataGenerator]

Comment: What image `data type` are you giving to `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` ? The assertion complains that the channel of the image is not equal to one. It appears you are not giving it a `grayscale` image (1-channel). Maybe you are passing a `BGR` (3-channel) image, in which case you need a conversion before: `grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(BGRImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.

Comment: I've written that line of code in the function before setting the `color_mode` to `grayscale` but unfortunately I'm getting the same error with or without it.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the image you are testing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this what you means but I've edited the post with a code very much like the original code and I've tried to shorten it as much as I can.